# How to use jenkin build parameter in build step written in .net as script?

Tags: c#, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have created a freestyle project with build parameters in Jenkin. But I am not sure how to access those parameters in the build step written using ".net as script".
[image]

Any input around this will be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to jenkin help. Build parameters are accessible using "GetSessionEnv("Param")" function. Below is the example.
[image]